# Submit the form after submit ( Ruby on Rails )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a newbie on Ruby on Rails

I have a regular form in a "new" page.
I hope when the user fulfilled the form and submit this form.
The page can popup a bootstrap modal and display the full content the user just typed in the form.(like a confirm page)

How can I do this?

---

I found this 
http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=11255
seems it can help me solve my problem
but can I change `<div id="preview">` to a bootstrap modal(or other popup)?

Comment: Please explain what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: normally in ruby on rails. It becomes a show page after submit.
I want to change it to a popup modal like bootstrap. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Still unclear. Do you want to change how the page is displayed before submitting or what happens after you submit it, or both? The title of your question is misleading.

Comment: What Hu Shau wants is to show the summary of the completed form so that the user can confirm the contents before actually saving it to the database. Essentially, needs hijack the form submit event, show a modal and then actually call submit on OK.

Comment: Yes!!!
How can I do this?

Comment: I re-edit my problems hope someone can help me  QQ
(forgive me that English is not my natural language.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to show the modal based on an onclick or onsubmit event

```
<%= submit_tag, :onclick => "launchConfirmPage();" %>
```

where `launchConfirmPage()` is some JS function that shows the modal filled with info. Then in that modal, have the actual submit button for the form. I'm not entirely sure of the specifics of how a submit_tag works, but you can also try using an anchor tag or button_tag to achieve the same thing if that doesn't work.

Comment: can you just display where should I add the modal? If I should add some `<script></script>` in my new page? how can I implement the detail like `<%= @post.description %>` in modal in my view?